# How can I represent a 2d UI?

Tags: opengl, c++, 2d

So, I wanted to start building a desktop application, which is of course with an interface, and I thought that OpenGL would be best.

The problem is, once I started following TheChernoProject's tutorials it got me a little confused. I know it's a state machine, but how exactly can I represent, for example, a rectangle I have drawn on the screen? How can I organize it, so I have a couple rectangles with different positions and sizes, which represent the interface?

Here is the code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define ASSERT(x) if(!(x)) __debugbreak();
#define GLCall(x) GLClearError();\
    x;\
    ASSERT(GLLogCall(#x, __FILE__, __LINE__))

static void GLClearError()
{
    while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR);
}

static bool GLLogCall(const char* function, const char* file, int line)
{
    while (GLenum error = glGetError())
    {
        std::cout << "[OpenGL Error] (" << error << "):" << function << " " << file << ":" << line << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

struct ShaderProgramSource
{
    std::string VertexSource;
    std::string FragmentSource;
};

static ShaderProgramSource ParseShader(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::ifstream stream(filepath);

    enum class ShaderType
    {
        NONE = -1, VERTEX = 0, FRAGMENT = 1
    };

    std::string line;
    std::stringstream ss[2];
    ShaderType type = ShaderType::NONE;
    while (getline(stream, line))
    {
        if (line.find("#shader") != std::string::npos)
        {
            if (line.find("vertex") != std::string::npos)
                type = ShaderType::VERTEX;
            else if (line.find("fragment") != std::string::npos)
                type = ShaderType::FRAGMENT;
        }
        else
        {
            ss[(int)type] << line << '\n';
        }
    }

    return { ss[0].str(), ss[1].str() };
}

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source)
{
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout << "Failed to compile " << (type == GL_VERTEX_SHADER ? "vertex" : "fragment") << " shader!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << message << std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader)
{
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Error!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    float positions[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.5f, -0.5f,
         0.5f,  0.5f,
        -0.5f,  0.5f,
    };

    unsigned int indices[] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &buffer));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * 2 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    GLCall(glEnableVertexAttribArray(0));
    GLCall(glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0));

    unsigned int ibo;
    GLCall(glGenBuffers(1, &ibo));
    GLCall(glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo));
    GLCall(glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(unsigned int), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW));

    ShaderProgramSource source = ParseShader("src/res/shaders/Basic.shader");
    std::cout << "VERTEX" << std::endl;
    std::cout << source.VertexSource << std::endl;
    std::cout << "FRAGMENT" << std::endl;
    std::cout << source.FragmentSource<< std::endl;
    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(source.VertexSource, source.FragmentSource);
    GLCall(glUseProgram(shader));

    GLCall(int location = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "u_Color"));
    ASSERT(location != -1);
    GLCall(glUniform4f(location, 0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f));
    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));

        GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr));

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    GLCall(glDeleteProgram(shader));

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you're fine on the graphics side, what you lack are data structures and way to organize your objects, and that's general C++.

Answer (score 1):

Building an application using OpenGL does not require you to use a specific programming language, since there is binding for pretty much any language you can think of nowdays.

> I know it's a state machine, but how exactly can I represent, for example, a rectangle I have drawn on the screen?

I don't understand how the two problems are correlated; 
OpenGL is a tool that you use to communicate and send commands to your GPU, also known as a **Graphics API**. 
Because of that, it has no notion of any "Rectangle" object.

> How can I organize it, so I have a couple rectangles with different positions and sizes, which represent the interface?

One way to do that would be to organize all your Rectangle data inside a class, pass it as a parameter to a  **Renderer**, that extracts all the data from it, and renders everything to the screen. This approach is *very* inefficent though.

That's why Batching Renderers are used: they usually contain one or more buffers, to which they write all the Rectangles' data, set them up, and send the whole thing with one or two drawcalls to the GPU. 
This way we have a `x to 1` ratio, which stands for "x sprites (or rectangles) rendered to the screen for the cost of 1 drawcall" which is much more efficent than having a 1:1 ratio (1 rect to 1 drawcall).

As Mikael already stated in his answer, developing a complete gui from a beginner standpoint is a non-trivial task. I highly suggest you to get very comfortable with OpenGL's basic and advanced concepts (like stencil buffers or text rendering) and your programming language of choice, before going any further.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the gamedev stack.

I'll try and address your questions one at a time, let's start off with

> So, I wanted to start building a desktop application

Let's just make sure we're on the same page and say that by application I assume you mean game or game engine. If you want to make a desktop application you'd be better off with something like C# and WindowsForm (For Windows, obviously).

> but how exactly can I represent, for example, a rectangle I have drawn on the screen? How can I organize it, so I have a couple rectangles with different positions and sizes, which represent the interface?

A rectangle in this sense is commonly referred to as a Sprite, which in turn contain little more than X,Y pos, size and a texture. You can then keep track of your Sprites in any number of ways, `std::vector` is for example a great container for such data. In preparation for drawing you'd go through your container (such as std::vector) and build up your buffers (VBO,VAO,IBO) and then in your draw step you'd simply tell OpenGL which buffers to use.

> Are there any specific tutorials which you could recommend me, or books, connected with the 2d aspects of OpenGL and building GUI with it?

Typically we tend not to link tutorials,books etc. since it's highly subjective and doesn't really have a clear answer. However, for what you're doing I'd suggest you hit pause on your TheCherno video marathon and head on over to [Learn OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com) which has been accepted as a good starting point by most people. In the first few tutorials or so you will gain the knowledge you need to draw a Sprite (hopefully!).

For the sake of completeness I would also say that writing an entire GUI library for a starter task might be a bit too big of a scope, you might want to start out smaller while getting the hang of OpenGL particulars. In the meantime you could use something like Dear ImGUI (ImGUI stands for immediate mode gui and the Dear part is their weirdly chosen name, it's a solid lib though and you can easily find out more via your favourite search engine Bing) which is rather lightweight and easy to use.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Well i meant a desktop application, like for example Visual Studio, or such development softwares, not a game nor a game engine, because in profession i am a game developer with Unreal Engine 4, and i wanted to start something new.

I know that C# would be best, but i don't think it's cross-platform, and i was hoping i can start doing such an application with C++

Comment: @Christian Panov C# is cross-platform thanks to the Mono project.

Comment: I know that it's subjective, but any recommendation for books or tutorials on C# GUI programming?

Comment: Don't know enough about cross platform development these days to give you any better answer I'm afraid! I gave up on portability years ago, it's hard enough to make something work on one platform! Also with the subject being more general development rather than gamedev this question is probably better suited for another stackexchange. Best of luck to you!